# How to print custom post type category name in a post/page

Tags: php, arrays, wordpress

I have been googling a lot of time to find a solution to this. I am using dream themes' nimble wordpress theme. I want to print the "dt_portfolio" custom post type's category name in th portfolio page. I have tried many ways to do that. But no use.
Finally I am stuck with this and used this code :

```
$ctname = get_the_terms( get_the_ID(), 'dt_portfolio_category' );
print_r ($ctname);
```

This gave me an output as below:

```
Array ( [27] => stdClass Object ( [term_id] => 27 [name] => Magazine [slug] => magazine [term_group] => 0 [term_taxonomy_id] => 33 [taxonomy] => dt_portfolio_category [description] => [parent] => 0 [count] => 3 [object_id] => 8560 [filter] => raw ) )
```

I want to print the "slug" from this array. Please help me to do that.

Comment: take a look http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/108570/how-to-display-categories-of-my-custom-post-type

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try it something like that :

```
  if($ctname ) {
      foreach($ctname as $data){

          $slug[] = $data->slug;

        }
       print_r($slug); // value inside slug array
    }
```

If `$ctname` has only 1 array then simply use `$slug` instead of `$slug[]` 
within `foreach` loop.

Hope it helps you some extent!

Comment: It works great. I got the result what i expected. Thanks a lot @Jenis Patel